# Torch softmax with value threshold

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to apply softmax with a value threshold. So like, given a threshold, the output still sums to 1, but every value is lower than the threshold.

This is my current code - I built Clip module to deal with Softmax output. However, I am receiving below error. What can I do to make it work?

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [200, 31]], which is output 0 of SoftmaxBackward0, is at version 3; expected version 0 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck
```

```
class Clip(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super().__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def clip(self, x):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if torch.all(x[i] < self.threshold):
                continue
            ind = torch.where(x[i] >= self.threshold)[0]
            new_x_i = torch.zeros_like(x[i])
            if len(ind) > 0:
                new_x_i[ind] = x[i][ind] / torch.sum(x[i][ind])
            new_x_i[~ind] = self.threshold
            x[i] = new_x_i  # Assign the modified tensor back to x[i]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.clip(x)

class GradientPolicy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_cols=5, time_window=50, threshold = 0.2):
        """DDPG policy network initializer."""
        super().__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.sequential = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=n_cols, out_channels=2, kernel_size=(1, 3)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=2, out_channels=20, kernel_size=(1, time_window-2)),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        self.final_convolution = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=21, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(1, 1))
        
        self.softmax = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        )
        self.clip = Clip(threshold)
        
    def mu(self, x, x2, x3):
        output = self.sequential(x)
        output = torch.cat([output, x2], dim=1)
        output = self.final_convolution(output)  
        output = torch.cat([output, x3], dim=2)

        output = torch.squeeze(output, 3)
        output = torch.squeeze(output, 1)  # shape [N, M + 1]
        output = self.softmax(output)
        output = self.clip(output)
        return output

    def forward(self, observation, last_action):
        mu = self.mu(observation, last_action, last_action)
        action = mu.cpu().detach().numpy().squeeze()
        return action
```

Answer (score 1):

The RuntimeError you're experiencing in PyTorch is due to an inplace operation in your `Clip` class, specifically `x[i] = new_x_i`. This operation modifies the original tensor `x`, which PyTorch requires unchanged for gradient calculation through its computational graph.

To resolve this, avoid inplace modifications of `x`; instead, work with a new tensor and return it. The revised Clip class below avoids inplace operations, preventing the error:

```
class Clip(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super().__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def clip(self, x):
        clipped_x = torch.zeros_like(x)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if torch.all(x[i] < self.threshold):
                clipped_x[i] = x[i]
                continue
            ind = torch.where(x[i] >= self.threshold)[0]
            new_x_i = torch.zeros_like(x[i])
            if len(ind) > 0:
                new_x_i[ind] = x[i][ind] / torch.sum(x[i][ind])
            new_x_i[~ind] = self.threshold
            clipped_x[i] = new_x_i
        return clipped_x

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.clip(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check your own code. When your code finds a row where a value is over the threshold, it replaces the value of the threshold, but also **zeros out all the other values** which I don't think is your intent.

The task you're describing is actually somewhat difficult to do efficiently. Maybe if you can provide more information about **why** you need this, I can come up with a better solution.

To illustrate why this is difficult, take the following code.

Given an input `x` and a `threshold`, we:

1. Compute the raw softmax values
2. create `threshold_mask` for values under the `threshold`
3. compute `under_threshold_sums` and `over_threshold_sums`. `under_threshold_sums` is the total current sum of the under threshold values we want to scale up. `over_threshold_sums` will be the total sum value of the over threshold values after we clip them to the threshold value
4. compute `rescale_values` as `(1-over_threshold_sums)/(under_threshold_sums)`. Say we have two values over the `threshold` of `0.3`. That means those two values will be clipped to `0.3`. The two over threshold values after clipping contribute `0.6` to the total. This means we want the sum of the under threshold values after scaling to sum to `0.4`. Hence the form `(1-over_threshold_sums)/(under_threshold_sums)`
5. compute `rescale_mask`. This mask has our `rescale_values` in all positions except the over threshold values
6. compute `scaled_softmax_vals` by clipping over threshold values to the `threshold` and scaling up the under threshold values so that the values still sum to 1.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = torch.randn(8, 32)/0.1 # divide by 0.1 to push more values over the thresold
threshold = 0.3

# 1
softmax_vals = F.softmax(x, -1)

# 2
threshold_mask = softmax_vals < threshold

# 3
under_threshold_sums = (softmax_vals * threshold_mask).sum(-1)
over_threshold_sums = threshold * (~threshold_mask).sum(-1)

# 4
rescale_values = (1-over_threshold_sums)/(under_threshold_sums)

# 5
rescale_mask = rescale_values.unsqueeze(1).expand(-1, softmax_vals.shape[-1])
rescale_mask = rescale_mask.masked_fill(~threshold_mask, 1)

# 6
scaled_softmax_vals = softmax_vals.clip(max=threshold) * rescale_mask
```

This approach accomplishes:

1. clipping over threshold values to the threshold value
2. scaling the under threshold values so that the total softmax values still sum to 1

**HOWEVER** there is a problem. Upscaling an under threshold value might result in creating a **new** over threshold value. This is what makes your question particularly challenging. You would have to apply the above code **iteratively** until all values are below the threshold, which might not have a convergence guarantee.

There is also another issue where having lots of really small values in your softmax output (ie 0.99999... for one value and tiny values for everything else) will cause this rescaling to produce nans.

I would suggest interrogating *why* you need this specific type of softmax rescaling, and why more conventional methods like temperature scaling or label smoothing don't fit your needs.